# Can we re-open this question asking how to throttle bandwidth per-user?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

This question, '[Is there an easy way to limit user bandwidth usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-limit-user-bandwidth-usage)' was closed as a duplicate. The possible duplicate, '[How I can limit Download/Upload bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth)' does not answer the new question, only addressing per-OS, per-network interface, and per-application rate limiting. Nothing there about **per-user**, which I think is an interesting question.

Can it be re-opened, or at least merged into the dupe (and the additional component about per-user limiting addressed)?

Comment: What does it mean to "merge" a question with *no answers* into another question? Do you just mean to edit the older question to add a fourth bullet point saying, "A particular user"?

Comment: [status completed]

Comment: @EliahKagan Editing it in as a fourth bullet point risked having that component of the question overlooked, since the dupe has an accepted answer. I wanted feedback from others as to what was the best way to handle this. Moot point now, but I wanted to make sure you got an answer to your comment.

Comment: @TomBrossman I agree, that's why I was confused about the "merging" thing. I'm glad we got this sorted out; I wonder if [that](http://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth) itself really works as one question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be resolved, at least for now. The question has been reopened. It appears there was a little bit of opposition to reopening it (judging from the reopen review queue history), but nobody has posted here or there to object to it being reopened.

While people should feel free to post other answers here, I think the situation has pretty much worked itself out.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the "per user" bullet is a more general case of the "per application", and therefore I'm not sure it should have a separate question.

The "per application" (and, 'all applications of one user' case) is a tricky one and the possible answers would look a lot like each other.

Seeing as it a tricky one (more so then the other 2 points in that question), maybe the per-application part should be merged the other way around, into that new question, and get the attention it might deserve.